# Эффект высоты view

Tags: android, view

Стандартные кнопки(Button) андроид  имеют эффект высоты(края кнопки создают его). Как можно добиться этого эффекта для LinearLayout. Что бы он выглядел выше.

Comment: Как вариант используйте библиотеку CardView, на которую можно накидать своих компонентов, и задать ей высоту elevation

Answer (score 2):

Создания эффекта слоев появился в Material design, вот ссылки на примеры:

[Android elevation](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/material/shadows-clipping.html)

[дополнительная ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26728570/android-appcompat-21-elevation)

Answer (score 1):

Как уже сказали, программно придать высоту можно только с API level 21, посредством:

```
android:elevation
```

В более ранних версиях, эффект высоты можно придать, как вариант, использованием 9-patch изображений в качестве background'a View.

[image: 9-patch]

Чем интенсивнее и больше тень, тем больше визуально будет казаться что элемент приподнят над остальными компонентами разметки.

Answer (score -2):

```
android:layout_height
```

Задает высоту для Lyaout

Comment: вы немного путаете высоту макета с эффектом приподнятости  вьюхи над остальными вьюхами (по оси z)